# Query to return value based on min of another column and customer ID?

Tags: sql

I'm still pretty new to SQL and I can't seem to find anything on this problem and am seeking help. I have ways to accomplish it but it requires using many more SQL queries than I believe is required. I'm sure there's a faster way to do it. I am basically trying to do something like:

```
select Date
from Table
where ID = 1 and amount = min(amount)
```

I know that is a non working query. But I'm trying to get the date of the minimum amount `ID 1` has listed in the table.

```
ID  Date            Amount
1   3/21/17 4:00    5
2   3/20/17 8:00    4
3   3/22/17 12:00   6
1   3/18/17 17:00   4
2   3/19/17 17:00   2
1   3/20/17 17:00   2
```

The result I'm looking for would be `3/20/17 17:00`. Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Subquery: `select date from table where id = 1 and amount = (select min(amount) from table where id = 1)`

Comment: Which dbms are you using? You've product specific answer(s)...

Comment: jarlh I'm using SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? (if you want min amount for every ID, otherwise remove ID from subquery):

```
SELECT T1.ID, DATE, AMOUNT
FROM T1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT ID, MIN(AMOUNT) AS MIN_AM FROM T1 GROUP BY ID) B ON T1.ID = B.ID AND T1.AMOUNT = B.MIN_AM
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

`SELECT TOP 1 Date
 FROM Table
 WHERE ID = 1
 ORDER BY Amount ASC, Date ASC`